# Redirecting to "old" site

Tags: maintenance-mode

I copied files and database of a Drupal 7 site to another domain.
When I put the site in maintenance mode, and I login, I am redirected and logged in to the *old* site. I cleared the cache, also in the database, but the result is the same. When the site is not in maintenance mode, this doesn't happen.

Additionally, I have to say that I created an SSL connection and checked _Use a symbolic link from private_html to public_html - allows for same data in http and https_. I don't know if this has something to do with that.

Where is the responsible file? What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the $base_url variable to the new site domain. This is in the /sites/default/settings.php file.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is usefull. I messed up some settings with the http:// and https:// but now I set everyting back and can continue